# TeamCity with BitBucket Cloud Commit Status Publisher. 404 Errors

Tags: git, bitbucket, teamcity-9.0

I'm having problems getting the commit status publisher to work.

Details:

- TeamCity 9.1 Commit Status Publisher Plugin version:
  snapshot-20160523141816 Bitbucket Cloud
- git repository type on
  bitbucket.org

VCS Settings:

- Configured to use the private key auth (w/ uploaded key)
- Multiple branches configured.
- Not using VCS Labeling
- No PUSH URL specified (should be failing back to FETCH URL, right?)

Commit Status Publisher Settings:

- I've experimented with these settings, neither email addresses nor
  usernames work.

[image: Commit Status Publisher Configuration Dialog]

But whenever something should publish a commit message, I get this pop up in the TeamCity build configuration list:

> Publish status error in build #730 {build id=68270,
>   buildTypeId=Project_BuildConfigurationName}:  Cannot publish status to
>   Bitbucket Cloud for VCS root Rootname: response code: 404, reason: NOT
>   FOUND, message: 'Resource not found'

One odd setup thing is that I'm using the ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443 address to get around some outbound firewall restrictions, though I doubt that would be causing the problem.

Do I need to have the VCS configured with a service account user instead of an SSH Deployment Key? I would rather not do that, if possible.

Comment: This version seems to have some bugs.. I'm trying to connect to on- premise Bitbucket Server(former Atlassian Stash) but getting error with message that it can't connect to UpSource:

"Publish status error in build #X {build id=X, buildTypeId=Messaging_Messaging}: Cannot publish status to Upsource for VCS root MessagingVCSRoot: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null"

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion that I'm coming to as well. 

I just can't tell if which of my permutations (multiple branches, alternative ssh URL in VCS root, using SSH key auth) is causing the problem, and I can't tell if I work with Atlassian or JetBrains to get it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commit status publisher parses the url you use [incorrectly](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-46969). As a workaround switch to the standard ssh url git@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git.

Comment: Good to know that that's where the problem is, I wound up using the altssh alias as a workaround for outbound network restrictions, so this workaround is incompatible with a different workaround. Ugh.

Comment: You can install the latest build of plugin (https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=TeamCityPluginsByJetBrains_CommitStatusPublisher_Master), the issue is fixed there.

Comment: Or even easier - upgrade to TeamCity 10.0.2, which contains the fix

Answer (score 0):

Not found means that your user cannot find the repository specified. Usually this means that the vcs settings on the client side are incorrect.

It seems that the issue is that there is no user dedicated for the build itself. **You are unable to use deployment keys to write to the repository. In any shape or form. ** Usual practice is to create a 'build'/'jenkins'/'teamcity' user that has permission to write build output to the bit bucket cloud itself. This is the same as the creation of any other user.

My next question would be do you need to write this information back to the bit unkept cloud itself or just contain the build status externally inside your teamcity instance. Assuming you have good reason to do this you will absolutely need a build user.

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem when using a newly created service account.

Comment: Did you create a specific user? What do you mean service account

Comment: I did create a specific user, that's what I mean by "service account".I created a new Bitbucket Cloud user and told TeamCity to use that user account and it still doesn't work.

Comment: How did you connect the two services? Did you create the public/private keypair?

Comment: See my other answer, I think this answer is going the wrong direction for you. If the other one is more useful, I'll delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this specific error message is unable to render the name of the root itself. Which suggests it isn't in the system itself.

```
Publish status error in build #730 {build id=68270,
buildTypeId=Project_BuildConfigurationName}: Cannot publish status to
Bitbucket Cloud for VCS root Rootname:<root_should_be_here> response
code: 404, reason: NOT FOUND, message: 'Resource not found'
```

See the:
[Source of the error message, see line 125.](https://github.com/JetBrains/commit-status-publisher/blob/178656b99f1efaf6bd36d110d93619eaff8d48e8/commit-status-publisher-server/src/main/java/jetbrains/buildServer/commitPublisher/bitbucketCloud/BitbucketCloudPublisher.java)

Also potentially interesting: [Source of the Repository Object](https://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/6.0/jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/BuildRevision.html)

This means that your bitbucket repo itself hasn't been registered correctly, this is very different from your ability to connect to the repo itself, it *should* still be able to be registered without the connection itself.

Interestingly this seems to be similar to an issue descripted on the  [Teamcity Common Issues](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Common%20Problems), where it suggests, if:

> VCS root with id "XXX" does not exist
> The build configuration or template reference a VCS root which is not defined in the system.
> Remedy actions: Restore the VCS root or create a new VCS root with the id noted or edit the file noted in the message to remove the reference to the VCS root.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what "Restore the VCS root" means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

It's **undoubtedly** to do with

```
final VcsRootInstance root = revision.getRoot();
```

not being able to find the root instance of the git repository. If you can I'd suggest trying this without that firewall there because there may be an issue synchronizing with the server as [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Roots) page notes

> TeamCity regularly queries the version control system for new changes and displays the changes in the Build Configurations that have the root attached

getRoot() is [supposed](http://javadoc.jetbrains.net/teamcity/openapi/6.0/jetbrains/buildServer/serverSide/BuildRevision.html#getRoot()) to be returning the

> version of VCS root checked out for the build.

and note that this is from the interface `Interface SVcsRoot`

which is the

> Server side class for the vcs root.

So this could definitely be a server side configuration issue that needs to be remedied with a root [reconfiguration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Roots).

Comment: I don't know how I would reconfigure the VCS root, as it works for everything _but_ the commit status notifier.  

It also seems odd to me that the build status notifier UI wants a username and password while my VCS configuration has a (working) SSH key that is associated with an account with read/write permissions.

Comment: After reconfiguring the VCS root, I'm no longer getting a 404 error, but I am getting these errors in the teamcity server log.

`INFO - .CommitStatusPublisherListener - Event: buildFinished, build #29 {build id=69725, buildTypeId=[vcs_root_name]}, cannot find revision for publisher bitbucketCloud, skip it`