# TeamCity Commit Status Publisher error

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, teamcity

The problem is that I am getting this kind of an error:

```
Publish status error in build #41 {build id=111, buildTypeId=Sandbox_Build}: Cannot publish status to Upsource for VCS root https://bitbucket.org/cogdevs/sandbox#refs/heads/master:
response code: 404, reason: NOT FOUND
```

I've found similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37556213/teamcity-with-bitbucket-cloud-commit-status-publisher-404-errors), where TS mentioned that he somehow reconfigured VCS, but it was not specified in which way, so I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I was using 'Atlassian Cloud', but in status publisher I somehow put 'Atlassian Stash'